# Best way to condense a list of option type down to only elements that are not none?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm unexpectedly having a bit of trouble with going from a list of 'a option down to a list containing only the elements that are Some.

My initial attempt was:

```
    let ga = List.filter (fun xx ->
        match xx with
        | Some(g) -> true
        | None -> false) gao
```

But of course, this result type is still 'a option list. I don't know how to use List.map to condense this, because you have to handle all cases in a match statement. I have an ugly solution, but I'm wondering if there is something better.

Ugly:

```
    let rec gOptRemove gdec gacc = 
        match gdec with 
        | head :: tail -> 
            match head with 
            | Some(a) -> gOptRemove tail (a :: gacc)
            | None -> gOptRemove tail gacc
        | [] -> gacc
```

I would prefer to find a non-recursive solution or find out what the standard way is for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Simply

```
List.choose id
```

as in

```
> [Some 4; None; Some 2; None] |> List.choose id;;
val it : int list = [4; 2]
```

[List.choose](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#choose)

[id](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#id)

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Had no idea that function existed.

Comment: The reason this works: List.choose wants to turn an `'a` into a `b option`. `id` is suitable for this because it turns a `'c option` into a `'c option`.

Comment: ...wow, that's clever.  Is this how your brain thinks all the time?

Comment: Just let the types guide you.  You want a function that contains `option` in its signature but returns just a `list` (not a list of options).  Look though the API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx ), and there's only one such function, `choose`, and now you're already 95% the way there.

Comment: Hm, as an aside, this appears to be my 1000th answer on stackoverflow.  I hope it is worthy of the honor.  :)

Comment: I read up on choose and replaced an earlier List.map with choose. Its a neat function when dealing with potential not-found or missing results. Grats on the 1000th answer.

Comment: GTK, I was also using similar code: `fun s -> s |> Seq.filter Option.isSome |> Seq.map (function Some(e) -> e | _ -> failwith "")`

Comment: @Brian, this is a good candidate as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720318/examples-of-functional-programs-writing-themselves-via-type-analysis

Comment: @Brian, keep on shining you crazy diamond!

Comment: For Haskell users looking for mapMaybe in F#, it's called List.choose .

Comment: This is one of my favourite answers on SO.  A little slice of code loveliness!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Option module functions to filter out the Options with values and then create a list of the values:

```
let concreteTypeList =
    optionTypeList
    |> List.filter (fun v -> Option.isSome v)
    |> List.map (fun v -> Option.get v)
```