# F# How to get value of Some from a list

Tags: f#

I have a list of options such as [Some 1; Some 2]. My aim is to get the values of Some elements without using pattern matching and options.get functions.

I have a testfunction which returns ('a -> 'b) option -> 'a option -> 'b option.
To achieve my goal, how can i use this function?

```
let test xa xb = 
  match xa with
  | None -> None
  | Some el -> Option.map el xa
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to condense a list of option type down to only elements that are not none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548532/best-way-to-condense-a-list-of-option-type-down-to-only-elements-that-are-not-no)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the values of the `Some` elements with the `List.choose` function, which does almost exactly that.

```
[Some 1; Some 2] |> List.choose id
// Returns [1; 2]
```

The semantics of the `List.choose` function is that it lets you chose some elements of the list by providing a function, which for every element returns either `Some` or `None`. Elements for which the function returns `None` are discarded, and the `Some` results are unwrapped and returned as a list. You can think of this function as a combination of `map` and `filter` in one.

Because the elements of your list are already of the `option` type, your choosing function would be `id`, which is a standard library function that simply returns its argument unchanged.

Comment: Can i achieve that with List.foldback?

Comment: @BDermier You can achieve anything with fold. But the folding function would need to contain pattern matching, which the OP doesn't want to do for some reason.